# Tool to detect errors in application's execution logic

Tags: debugging, programming, control-flow

I want to detect errors in application's execution logic. E.g.:

- forgot to call `free()` on address returned by `malloc()`
- did not close file handle returned by `open()`
- invalid flags passed to `open()`
- invalid file handle passed to `poll()`
- `write()` called on fd that wasn't opened for writing
- pass invalid flags to `open()` e.g. open("/etc/fstab", 4)
- calling `close()` on an invalid fd
- ...

I think there are hundreds more.

Maybe the tool can be run similar to `ftrace` or `strace`, but a kernel log containing the faulty calls would be sufficient too.

Comment: *- forgot to call `free()` on address returned by `malloc()`* - This is not about the kernel, but about memory management. 

*did not close file handle returned by `open()`* - This is not strictly necessary. You've lumped together very different classes of errors, the first two are programming errors, not kernel errors.

Comment: Do you want to do this statically or dynamically?

Comment: @JörgWMittag What do you mean?

Comment: Do you want to detect these conditions as they are happening at runtime or do you want to detect them without running the program?

Comment: @JörgWMittag At runtime. I think a static tool cannot know for example which arguments will be passed to open() or whether free() will be called.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> forgot to call `free()` on address returned by `malloc()`

Well, `malloc` and `free` aren't kernel calls! What `malloc()` (which is a libc library function, normal user process code!) does

1. look up in the memory pool it keeps whether there's an available chunk of the requested size
2. if so, mark it as used and return it to the program, if not, call `sbrk` (or equivalently, mallocing of anonymous memory was common) to ask the kernel for an amount of new virtual memory pages, add these to the pool, and then satisfy the program's request.

`free` just takes s piece of memory previously returned through `malloc`; if so, it marks it as unused in the memory pool. (If not, undefined behaviour happens, but most libc's will abort at that point.) Most implementations of `free` don't ever try to even return the memory to the OS!

Now, if you want memory sanitation, there's tools (valgrind, `gcc -fsanitize` and more) that watch these `free` and `malloc` calls, and even trace whether the address of a `malloc`ed piece of memory is still "saved" somewhere in the program, or whether, e.g. at the end of a function, the pointer holding that address just ceases to exist, so that nobody can possibly remember that the memory was allocated. That would be an actual fault; just not immediately freeing memory, or deferring the freeing to the end of the program is not a problem, at all. The whole point of `malloc` is that you get memory with a potentially infinite lifetime!  (hint: if you worry about these kinds of things, and you'd be right to, don't write C. Write in a language that allows for object life times to be tracked properly. That would be languages like Rust, or C++, but the latter [only if not taught by someone who thinks of C++ as extension to C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk). I have large programs where I never once used `new` or worse, `malloc` in my C++ code. Smart pointers can take a lot of the pitfalls of your shoulders, even in C++, which very much *allows* you to do manual memory control, but in modern variants also very much encourages you not to by offering zero-cost object lifetime tracking. )

> did not close file handle returned by `open()`

That's not a problem! Even more than with memory, it's perfectly acceptable and even sensible to keep files open till the end of a program; for example, locks on files wouldn't work if you relinquish them right away. And a control interface would need to be kept open until the program shuts down.

Again, if you're worried that within your program's control flow, you might be opening thousands of files and forget to close them, don't write in C, but in a language where a file handle has a life time and can close the underlying file descriptor when not needed anymore.

Just: "there's a file opened, it has not yet been closed" simply isn't a problem, *especially* not on POSIX systems, where concurrent file access is normal and in many aspects even well-defined.

> invalid flags passed to `open()`

How do you know that, other than things that return an error code anyways?

I mean, it's very normal for a library to check whether a file can be opened "write + append" mode, but it's not a problem if it can't be.

If you want to observe any time a system call is made, get its arguments and what it "returns" to user land, the `ptrace` syscall is your friend, as e.g. used by the popular `strace` program. Other options involve writing eBPF probes or uprobes, which can be used for very efficient and even "intelligently filtering" logging of such things.

> invalid file handle passed to `poll()`

Same problem as before, this might just be your program checking whether a file handle can be polled; that's not the case for all (pseudo-) file systems.

Additionally, `poll` is actually also the name of a wrapper function (symbol) supplied at least by glibc if necessary, and "invalid" to that might be different than "invalid" to the `poll` syscall.

Comment: +1 for sanitizers as I believe its the only right way to go. Rust offers quite a lot. I can only remember times when I would never run  my programs before passing them through lint.

Comment: “it's perfectly acceptable and even sensible to keep files open till the end of a program” — Won't that depend on the pattern of use? It should be fine to keep the _same_ (limited number of) files open continually; but if if opens more files the longer it runs, then it had _better_ close them at the same rate, else it'll cause trouble sooner or later! (And since the question asks about an ‘application’, it seems reasonable to assume it could be running for an indefinite period.)

Comment: @gidds that's very true! Point is that you need some analysis, and domain knowledge of what the application does, to know whether a usage pattern is problematic. I'll go as far as saying the pure observation of files opened is at best a small puzzle piece :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Agreed! But I think small pieces of the puzzle are the best we can hope for — AIUI, the full question as posed would be on a par with solving the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)…

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have added some more examples. Maybe you can say something about them. For example when the program calls open("/etc/fstab", 4) it's 100% safe to say that there is something wrong in the program. (Because 4 is not a valid flag.) How to detect something like this? Use strace?

Comment: Also I meant passing a fd to poll() which has never been opened. Something like this is 100% safe an error that may never happen. I think that's not so hard to detect.

Comment: yes, that would sound like a job for `ptrace` as used by `strace`, or for a BPF probe that simply attaches to the syscall of interest. But it's **not** 100% safe to say there's something wrong if you pass 4 as flag to open. Flags are checked with `& BITMASK`, so if you set "unused" bits, that's not a problem. On the contrary, that might be a bit used by a future version of the syscall, and might not have effect *yet*, but then.

Comment: Yes but that's very unlikely. The sanitizer tool could provide a command line options to decide whether to report such things.

Comment: And that's where strace will fail. I think it won't report such an error. But I think it will work for most things.

Comment: I'm repeating myselfe, but as said, you can write your own checker using `ptrace`. Don't know why you're so hung up on `strace`!

Answer (score 4):

The first of these, failing to free a block of memory allocated by `malloc()`, doesn’t necessarily involve the kernel — memory allocations are handled by the C library. Valgrind’s [Memcheck](https://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#memcheck) can detect these.

To trace errors returned by the kernel, you can run your program with `strace -Z` (available since `strace` 5.2): this will only trace system calls which return an error. You’ll still need to post-process the result to look for example for `EBADFD`, `EINVAL` etc.

Note that failing to call `free()` or `close()` isn’t necessarily an error; such resources are freed when the program exits anyway, so there are cases where it’s perfectly acceptable to not relinquish resources explicitly.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that once you go as low-level as `strace -Z`, you've kind of departed from the stated goal of "detect[ing] errors in application's execution logic", as a kernel-call error could come from anywhere, not just the application. (By which I mean, the kernel call that returns an error could be made by a function in a shared library loaded by a program module dynamically-loaded by _another_ shared library that's linked with the application in question.) Some applications are **directly** responsible for very few of the kernel calls made on their behalf.

Comment: @FeRD yes, the question [changed substantially](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/708783/revisions) (in intent) since I wrote this answer. It was initially titled “Tool to detect faulty kernel calls”.

Comment: @StephenKitt Understood. Honestly I think the question has lost all (useful) focus, which is really what I was responding to. The answer is perfectly good for what it is. The question, in its current form, reminds me of the Babbage anecdote about people asking him whether his Analytical Engine would produce   correct answers if they input wrong data.

Answer (score 0):

There are various static code analysis tools available to find common coding errors like this. I can't say if it covers all of your scenarios but SonarQube is one such tool with support for the C language: https://www.sonarqube.org/features/multi-languages/c

There are hundreds of SonarQube rules for C: https://rules.sonarsource.com/c

[image: SonarQube - C - Dynamically allocated memory should be released]

If static code analysis isn't sufficient, you may need dynamic analysis to examine the running program: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_program_analysis